# Microsoft Identity Headless Login

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Windows service that cycles through four different mailboxes, reads the emails into a CMS system, then deletes the emails. I have been using simple sign-on with IMAP, but apparently Microsoft has deprecated this option and I need to move to Microsoft Identity.

In my corporate environment I cannot use an app account due to security issues, so I have to use user logins.

Can I authenticate to a user using Microsoft Identity headless in a Windows service?  I don't want to have to authenticate manually each time the service starts up, plus I am not even sure if I can have 4 Microsoft user accounts active at the same time.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the [EWS web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange).

To use Microsoft oauth you need a azure application registration with the delegated api permission [EWS.AccessAsUser.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth).

With this setup you can either access the mailbox of a user with the users login token (i.e. either using their username and password or interactive user login) or you can use [user impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-configure-impersonation?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

To use user impersonation you need a username and password of a user that is allowed to access the mailboxes you need access for.

Another way to go is to setup a azure application registration with a application api permission to [EWS.AccessAsUser.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth).  This allows you access to all mailboxes.  I would not recommend this as people may not like the fact you can access any mailbox in an organization.

Following the code examples from the URL above will get you access to only online mailboxes.  To support a hybrid setup where the mailbox is either online or on-premise the missing link is to autodiscover the mailbox server URL(so you don't hardcode it to the Exchange online URL).  This has been made very simple with [autodiscover v2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-community-blog/microsoft-teams-and-on-premises-mailboxes-part-2-teams-calendar/ba-p/2232602).  It's a simple https request where the result is the URL of the exchange server to use.

I would recommend using the user impersonation along with autodiscover v2 for the most secure and most flexible setup.